# Date is not updated in Data Grid View in Window Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I used MS Access to save data in my ASP.NET Window application. When I update date in Data Grid View it shows error “Syntax error in UPDATE statement” but when I update other field like Name, Contact No. then these fields is easily updated.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

 OleDbConnection con1;
        OleDbDataAdapter da1;
        DataTable dt1;
        OleDbCommandBuilder cmb1;

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Day Book Data\db\DayBook.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
            string query1 = "select * from paypayment";
            da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query1, con1);
            dt1 = new DataTable();
            con1.Open();
            da1.Fill(dt1);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;

            con1.Close();
        }

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 cmb1 = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da1);
            da1.Update(dt1);
}
```

Comment: Psychic debugging suggests that you're including the date as a string, instead of using parameterized SQL. However, it would be much easier to help you if you'd show your code instead.

Comment: [How To Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the date format, use date format : "dd-MMM-yyyy"